# $\sum f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x) = n^2 x^2e^{-n^2 x^2} - (n-1)^2 x^2e^{-(n-1)^2 x^2} , x \in [0,1]$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

To prove that the series $\sum f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x) = n^2 x^2e^{-n^2 x^2} - (n-1)^2 x^2e^{-(n-1)^2 x^2} , x \in [0,1]$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

One way I tried doing that is showing that integration of the sum and sum of integration are not same.

Obtaining the partial sum $s_n(x)$ to be $n^2 x^2e^{-n^2 x^2}$ we have $lim_{n \to \infty} s_n(x) = 0.$

Thus integration of the sum is $0$.

But finding difficult to do sum of integration.

Guessing that the problem is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Are you certain that the sequence fails to converge uniformly?

Comment: the problem is given in a book this way....

Comment: Does the "problem" ask to prove it fails, or does the problem request to determine whether it fails to converge uniformly?  It is easy to show that $n^2x^2e^{-n^2x^2}$ does not uniformly converge.  But the difference of these two individually non-uniformly converging sequences might actually converge uniformly.

Comment: i wrote exactly what is given in book.....

Comment: @Dr.MV: Note that the series is telescoping, $f_n=g_n-g_{n-1}$ with $g_0=0$ and $g_n(x)=g(n^2x^2)$ where $g(y)=ye^{-y}$. Thus the partial sums are $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k=g_n$.

Comment: @LutzL I hadn't noticed that this was a series.  Rather, I thought it was only a sequence.

Comment: Well, that's understandable, the partial sum sequence *is* much simpler than the series (as is often the case in the telescoping case).

Answer (score 2):

While the commutation of integration and summation is a consequence of uniform convergence, it is not the definition of it. Thus it may not be the most advantageous path to take, especially if the integrals prove difficult to evaluate.

---

Since the pointwise limit of the sequence $\{s_n\}$ of partial sums is $0$, you have to compute the suprema resp. supremum norms $$\|s_n-0\|_∞=\|s_n\|_∞=\sup_x|s_n(x)|$$ to discuss uniform convergence. Uniform convergence is equivalent to the norms converging to zero.

---

Note that the maximum of $g(y)=ye^{-y}$ is attained for $y=1$ with value $g(1)=e^{-1}$. Further, $$s_n(x)=g(n^2x^2).$$

Comment: i don't understand please help more

Comment: Uniform convergence means (here) that $\|s_n\|_\infty=\sup_x|s_n(x)|$ converges to zero. Thus if you have a control on the supremums, or their actual values, you can decide on the uniform convergence. Now if $g(y)=ye^{-y}$ then $s_n(x)=g(nx)$,...

Comment: @LutzL Note that $f_n$ is comprised of the difference of terms, both of which have the same maximum value of $e^{-1}$.  So, it isn't so obvious (to me) that this sequence fails to converge uniformly.

Comment: It is not the $f_n$ that are required to converge (or not), but the partial sums $s_n$. We are not talking about the Weierstraß test here.

Comment: @user8795.From Lutzl's answer we have $s_n(1/n)=1/e$ but $s_n$ converges to $0$ so the convergence is not uniform.